# Django checkbox field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to add a checkbox that if ticked will make a attribute in my model false.

My model is:

```
 class Topic(models.Model):
        """A topic the user is learning about"""
        text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
        public = False

My forms.py (where the checkbox should go) is:

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
```

And my function:

```
def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Could you please tell me what I need to change in order that when a checkbox in forms is checked, the public variable becomes True, and then the function Topics displays public topics as well as just the owners.

Thanks

Milo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`models.BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.BooleanField) renders itself [as a checkbox](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.BooleanField). Is either `True` or `False`. So:

```
# models.py

class Topic(models.Model):
    # ...
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)


# forms.py

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ["text", "public"]
        labels = {"text": "", "public": "label for public"}
```

If you want to also accept `null` values, then you should use [`models.NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField).

Comment: But that field does not show up in the detailed view, right?

Comment: It does render as a checkbox in the detailed view. What makes you think otherwise?